# Probability and Statistics books for a prospective econometrician

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request

I've recently got accepted into a PhD Program in Economics and I'm looking for textbooks that can help me in my preparation. 
I need a book (or books) that fit my needs and that take into account my background.

Needs:
-Mathematical rigor
-Introductory
-Suited to an Economics student
-I'm especially interested in Econometrics, so I would not want a book which focus heavily on topics studied by Statisticians and not by Econometricians.

Background:
-I've taken one course on Real Analysis and some introductory lectures on Measure Theory.

Topics:
Probability: multivariate random variables, expectation, conditional expectation, limit theorems.
Statistics: Estimation, properties of estimators, hypothesis testing, sample distributions, Asymptotic Theory

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used Greene's *[Econometric Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131395386)*, during my studies. Rigorous, but not so easy.

You'll probably also need something on time series, I'd suggest Brockwell & Davis' *[Time Series: Theory and Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441903194)*.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend this combination:

*[Statistical Inference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8131503941)* by Casella & Berger

*[Econometrics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691010188)* by Fumio Hayashi